# Flask App Import Statement for DB not working

Tags: python, flask

I'm new to flask and python and I've been facing the same issues with importing or loading flask applications. For some reason the import statement is able to locate db when I hover over it. But when I run `flask run` it gives me `Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/gio/Desktop/final project server side/my_app/catalog/script.py", line 2, in <module> from my_app import db ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_app'`

Here is the full project repo: https://github.com/officialgio/final-python-project

The file I'm getting the error in is `script.py`

script.py:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from my_app import db
from models import *

# Create a Session
Session = sessionmaker(bind=db.engine)
session = Session()

# Create Waiters
waiter1 = Waiter(first_name='John', last_name='Doe', tax_number='123')
waiter2 = Waiter(first_name='Jane', last_name='Smith', tax_number='456')

# Add Waiters to the session
session.add_all([waiter1, waiter2])
session.commit()

# Create Menu Items
menu_item1 = Menu(item_name='Burger', description='Delicious burger', price=10.99)
menu_item2 = Menu(item_name='Pizza', description='Margherita pizza', price=12.99)

# Add Menu Items to the session
session.add_all([menu_item1, menu_item2])
session.commit()

# Create Customer Ticket
customer_ticket = CustomerTicket(arrival='2023-01-01 12:00:00', departed='2023-01-01 13:30:00', table_id=1, waiter_id=1)

# Add Customer Ticket to the session
session.add(customer_ticket)
session.commit()

# Create Orders for the Customer Ticket
order1 = Order(customer_ticket_id=customer_ticket.id, menu_item_id=menu_item1.id, quantity=2)
order2 = Order(customer_ticket_id=customer_ticket.id, menu_item_id=menu_item2.id, quantity=1)

# Add Orders to the session
session.add_all([order1, order2])
session.commit()

# Close the session
session.close()
```